# Replace url with link but with an added difficult

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hyperlink

In an editable iframe I am replacing the plain urls with links thanks to this regex:

```
function linkify(text) {
    var regex = /(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*/g;
    return text.replace(regex,"<a href='$&'>$&</a>");
}

var content = linkify($('.div').html());
```

My problem comes when I try to 'linkify' a string wich contain links, it creates a monster like this:

```
<a href="&lt;a href='http://google.com'&gt;http://google.com&lt;/a&gt;"></a><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
```

I think that this problem can be solved if I iterate over the DOM instead of analyze the html string, but before to try it I want to ask here if someone have any idea.

Thanks!

Comment: You've got the right solution in mind: look at the DOM piece by piece. You can still use a regex to recognize when you've got a plain URL that should be linkified, but you need to be able to recognize when it's already _is_ a link.

Comment: I think you are on the right link with iterating the DOM  Fortunately, the DOM gives you a nice NodeList called `document.links`

Comment: Suggested strategy: (1) find existing links, remember and replace with placeholders; (2) linkify; (3) replace placeholders with remembered links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and solved it by first stripping the html tags:

```
function strip_tags(str, allow) {
allow = (((allow || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join('');

var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi;
var commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
return str.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
return allow.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
});
}
```

And then running the urlify function:

```
function urlify(text) {
var exp = /(\b(http):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
}
```

See my fiddle to try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/gerbenzomp/UJMeR/3/